# D3.js Wildcard selection on SVG Path

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

The following is an svg path tag extracted from an svg file:

```
    <path id="GOR-SK;06;06-G4-0708" d="M50431.61,-2196.75l- 
    1912.93,0l0,302.8l0,1137.2l1912.93,0z" class="selectable"
    </path>
```

I am trying to style all path elements containing the string "06-G4-708" from the id attribute.

I am using D3.Js to do this but unfortunately I have not found the correct syntax.

What I have done so far is :

```
    d3.selectAll('path').classed('lime', d => d.id.indexOf('06-G4-708') >= 0);
```

This is throwing the following error message : [variable d not defined.]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you create the path and assign it an id you can set a class based on the `id`

```
d3.selectAll('path').classed('lime', d => d.id.indexOf('06-G4-708') >=0);
```